# Finding the inverse of a infimum function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, inverse-function

What is the inverse function of
$$f:t\mapsto \inf\{s\geq 0:\mu([0,s])>t\}$$

Can I just write:

$$f^{-1}:s\mapsto \inf\{t\geq 0:\mu([0,s])\leq t\}$$

$\mu$ is a measure.

Comment: I see no reason why you could just write that. Do you have proof that $f\circ f^{-1}$ is the identity function?

Comment: @5xum No, it's a transformation and I need the inverse function for that transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $f$ is not bijective. If, for example, $$\mu(A)=\begin{cases}|A| & \text{ if } A \text{ is finite}\\
\infty & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

then $f(t)=0$ for all $t>0$, so an inverse function cannot exist.

Comment: And if it is a finite measure?

Comment: If $\mu$ is a finite positive measure, then with $F(s)=\mu([0,s]),$ then $f$ is injective, and $f(t)=F(t+)$ , but if $F$ has a jump discontinuity at $t$ and if $f(t)=F(t+)$ your formula for $f^{-1}$ won't work.